# Tableau Calculation IF statement

Tags: tableau-api

**New to Tableau

I am trying to create a new column for that changes a cell to say 'Open' when it is equal to 0.

Currently I have this, but I can't compare an int and a string.

```
IF  [Carton Count] = 0 
THEN [Carton Count] = 'Open'
ELSE [Carton Count]
END
```

Any way to possibly do this without changing the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a new column with a distinct name from `[Carton Count]`, you can use this pattern.

```
IF  [Carton Count] = 0 
THEN 'Open'
ELSE STR([Carton Count])
END
```

If `[Carton Count]` is dimensional data, you can right click it and select `Aliases...` and manually change 0 to 'Open'.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just editing the SQL.

```
,CASE   
WHEN (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CARTON_ID) as varchar(10))) = '0'
THEN 'Open'
ELSE (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CARTON_ID) as varchar(10)))
END AS CARTON_COUNT
```

Comment: Where is the SQL ?  If it's Custom SQL in the data connection you will get better performance by NOT using Custom SQL and learning how to use Tableau by just pointing to the table/s and then doing a calculation (like above)

Comment: I have the SQL on an SSMS server.

Comment: What does the FULL SQL statement look like ?  Although you can just paste in SQL statements, you might be better to not do that and just join tables in Tableau ... .it will make it faster